# React thinks my Function Component is an Object (rather than a function) in a

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs, es6-modules

I have a React Function Component, `TitleBar` which I am trying to unit test with Jest.

When I import the component from a local file, the test runs OK.

```
import [TitleBarProps, default as TitleBar} from './TitleBar.tsx'
```

But when I import the identical file from an npm package using

```
import [TitleBarProps, default as TitleBar} from 'my-title-bar'
```

I get this error...

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

This usually suggest the component was incorrectly exported or imported, but I can't see what is different.

```
import React from "react";

export interface TitleBarProps = {
   Title: string
};

const TitleBar = ({ Title }: TitleBarProps) => {
   return <h1>{Title}</h1>;
}

export default TitleBar;
```

and a unit test which imports this component and tests it, like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { TitleBarProps, default as TitleBar } from './index';

...

describe('TitleBarProps', () => {
    const props: TitleBarProps = { Title: "The title" };

    it('renders without crashing', () => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');

        ReactDOM.render(
                <TitleBar {...props} />
            div,
        );

        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
    });
});
```

Comment: the bracket `[` in `import [TitleBarProps, default as TitleBar} from 'my-title-bar'` is it a typo?

Comment: There is no `my-title-bar` package, and the way the example works totally depends on specific package. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. A possible explanation for this error is that the package is CommonJS module and its export translates to `default` ES module export, not `*`.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes, a typo. sorry :)

Comment: @EstusFlask It might take a while to create a test repo, but  what you suggest sounds plausible, especially as this package works in the react.js app perfectly fine, but fails when imported into a jest test. How can I know what type of package it is? in the `title-bar.cjs.develoment.js`, the last line is `exports.default = TitleBar;`

Comment: `cjs` suggests it's CommonJS entry point. CommonJS `exports` object is translated to ESM `default` import, so having exports.default doesn't help because it will be available as `default.default` in ESM import. CJS package should have `exports.__esModule = true` in order to be treated correctly on ESM import. You can alternatively switch to ESM entry point for this package with moduleNameMapper and allowing it in transformIgnorePatterns. But the lack of __esModule is a bug in this package.

Comment: There's also a `title-bar.esm.js`, but its not referenced by the `index.js` Would by unit test detect that file instead?

Comment: @EstusFlask I manually added `exports.__esModule = true` into the `.dev.js` file and this fixed it :) Should the package be built in a particular way to get `__esModule` included?

Comment: Yes, it should. It depends on your tools how this should be enforced. It's not uncommon for CJS to not have this field because it can make the module work ambiguously but it's needed for the way you use it. The problem with ambiguity can be solved by not having `default`, only named exports.

Comment: Thanks! If you can add an answer, I can tick it!

Answer (score 0):

As @EstusFlack suggested in the comments on the question, this is caused by my jest unit test trying to consume my npm package's (CommonJS) file `title-bar.cjs.development.js`, which has an export like this:

```
exports.default = TitleBar;
```

So when `babel-jest` tries to consume this file, it tries to translate it from CommonJS into an ES module.

This causes it to create an `exports.default.default` command and in my Jest unit test it only sees the `default` Object, rather than the actual `TitleBar` function.

Adding this line into that file resolves the problem, but this is not the fix. This allows Babel to consume the file directly.

```
exports.__esModule = true;
```

The better approach (as suggested by @EstusFlack) is to not use a default export in the first place and use a Named export instead, like this:

```
exports.TitleBar = TitleBar;
```